# Android File on Internal Storage not found

Tags: android, internal

I'm trying to write a file in my app's android internal storage space. After so many trials, I was finally successful using this method [Writing/Reading Files to/from Android phone's internal memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306155/writing-reading-files-to-from-android-phones-internal-memory) . However, when I go to data/data/package_name/files, I cannot find my package, and cannot even find the MyFile.txt. In fact, I can't find them anywhere in internal memory. Why is that?

Comment: How are you looking for the file ? through file explorer could not be possible until you phone is rooted.

Comment: you can try emulator to check for files. Do u get FileNotFoundException ??

Comment: yes, my phone is not rooted. That makes sense then, but how come I can see other folders/files for other applications installed on my phone? What is the code that I can write to allow me to have a visible folder for my application?