# Android creating file on internal storage

Tags: android

I am trying to create a `.txt` file in `android`, I have tested a lot of options how to achieve this, I think the file is created but I can't find it, it should be writed somehow public in a public directory that I can access it.

Example:

```
cacheFile = new java.io.File(getFilesDir(), "cache.txt");
        if(cacheFile.exists() && !cacheFile.isDirectory()) {
            try {
                writer = new FileWriter(cacheFile);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cacheFile));
                String tempo;
                while((tempo = br.readLine()) != null){
                    Log.i("TEST","Reading from cache "+tempo);
                    if (tempo.contains("http")) {
                        musicUrl.add(tempo);
                    }
                    else {
                        myDataList.add(tempo);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
        else {
            try {
                Log.i("TEST", "Creating the cache ? " + cacheFile.createNewFile() + " in " + getFilesDir());
                writer = new FileWriter(cacheFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

What other option I've tried: [Android File on Internal Storage not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000148/android-file-on-internal-storage-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use one of the following:

```
getExternalFilesDir()
getExternalStoargeDir()
```

the first will create a file in `/sdcard/android/app.package/file`
the second will be the root of `/sdcard/`

The call that you currently make, `getFilesDir()`, is returning the path in `/data/data/app.package/file` which is not accessable to anything other then your application.

Comment: I don't have an SD card.

Comment: Exactly, that is the path where is creating the file.

Comment: `/sdcard/` is the path that is globally accessable. a physical sdcard would be located at `/sdcard-ext/` try adding permission to your manifes to write to external storage, and then using this. I am confident it will work.

Comment: so `/sdcard/` refers to internal storage of the phone ?

Comment: Thanks, all this time I was confused.

Comment: And this for the manifest permissions: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Yeah, it it kind of confusing; cheers, and happy coding.